# Let tastypie client do CRUD without foreign key lookups

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm using [TastyPie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/) to create a REST client/server for accessing some data about our system-level build post tests.  I'd like the client to be able to ignore the fact that *product* is stored internally as a foreign key and do CRUD operations using product and tag names.  In essence, I want client scripts to interact with "product" and "tag" as CharFields, but to save this information on the server as Foreign Keys.  Here's my api.py:

```
from tastypie import fields
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from models import Test, Product, Tag

class ProductResource(ModelResource):
    name = fields.CharField('name', unique=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        filtering = {'iexact', 'exact'}

class TagResource(ModelResource):
    name = fields.CharField('name', unique=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Tag.objects.all()
        filtering = {'iexact', 'exact'}

class TestResource(ModelResource):
    product = fields.ForeignKey(ProductResource, 'product', full=True)
    tags = fields.ForeignKey(TagResource, 'tags', full=True)
    command = fields.CharField('command')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Test.objects.all()
        filtering = {'product': tastypie.constants.ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
                     'tag': tastypie.constants.ALL_WITH_RELATIONS}
```

I'm currently working on a custom ApiField class that would do this using its own hydrate and dehydrate, but that made me feel like I'm probably missing something.  How can I allow the client to do, e.g.:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"product": "fisherman", "command": "go fish"}' /api/v1/test/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prepend a new URL to handle your commands:

```
class TestResource(ModelResource):
   ...
   def prepend_urls(self):
      return [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/commands$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('handle_commands'), name="api_handle_commands"),
    ]


def handle_commands(self, request):
   command = request.POST['command']
   product = Product.objects.get(name=request.POST['product'])
   # do your stuff
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to handle filtering.